# How to validate a Rails model against an enum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, rails-models

Similarly to how mongoose for nodejs has an enum validator whereby the value of the field must be one of the values in a predefined array, how would a mongoid model in Rails replicate this behavior?

ie.

```
field :category, type: String --> must be in one of [categoryA, categoryB, categoryC]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
validates :category, :inclusion => { :in => ["categoryA", "categoryB", "categoryC"] }
```